# JQuery for-loop with variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table out of different MySQL data. I want to highlight cells with the same ID in it on hover. I did that with a simple jQuery, the script is almost working but you see I've got the var nr and want the integer i to be added to the class string. What is my mistake, why isn't it working? If you change the **var nr = '.id_' + i;** to a static variable like **var nr = '.id_2';** it is working.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var nr = '.id_' + i;
    var bgcol = $(nr).css('backgroundColor');
    $(nr).hover(
      function(){
            $(nr).css({"background":"yellow"});
      },function(){
            $(nr).css({"background":bgcol});
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nkdny/210/

Solution, thanks to Karl-André Gagnon: http://jsfiddle.net/Nkdny/215 Look in the comments for details.

Comment: You're missing an `echo`.  You should be getting an error in your JS console.

Comment: drop the  table tag.

Comment: The php tag is relevant, because thats where the actual typo error is ;)

Comment: what are you two talking about? sneaky edit for the win :-)

Comment: In your `hover` functions, `nr` will always equal `.id_9` since `var` is not block scoped, `let` is. http://jsfiddle.net/Nkdny/215/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an echo in front of your php statement.

```
<?php echo $amount; ?>
```

Comment: Indeed, in the jsfiddle this mistake isn't there, I missed it here. But the real mistake was I used 'var' instead of 'let' so the 'i' always equals 9 as that is the last number in the loop.